# Transpose a table filled with vue

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to transpose a table which is filled using Vue?
The html now is:

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Temp(max)</th>
        <th>Temp(min)</th>
        <th>Rain</th>
        <th>Icon</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="forecast in forecasts">
        <td>{{forecast.date}}</td>
        <td>{{forecast.maxTemp}}°C</td>
        <td>{{forecast.minTemp}}°C</td>
        <td>{{forecast.rain}} mm</td>
        <td><i :class="translateIcon(forecast.icon)"></i></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But I want to change this table view to have the dates in Row 1, the max temp in Row 2, etc.

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GQYwJL?editors=1010

Comment: Yep! like that. I thought there might be an easier / less consuming way than transposing the dataset. But it will do.

Comment: There's no built in method for doing that in Vue (that I'm aware of); you'll have to do it yourself.